# JavaLauncher racing for the same resources

Tags: java, windows, stored-procedures, intellij-idea, race-condition

I have a shell (Windows) program that start IDEA intellj with JavaLuncher.
Intellij is stuck until I close the shell program.
Dose JavaLuncher start the intellij with shared resources with Shell ?

Comment: well, how does it start it?

Comment: What do you mean ? luncher.exec();

Comment: You should provide more details. Why do you need to run IDEA with JavaLauncher, how exactly your script configures IDEA to be run from it?